# How does the compiler determin on which platform it is running?

Tags: compiler-construction

In case of having an application that is supported on two different operating systems. There is a specific implementation for each operating system.I would like to know how does the compiler know on which platform it is running so that it compiles implementation X and not Y.

Comment: For example the `Java Virtual Machine` has native code, which is specific to each platform. I am not sure how can the `JIT` compiler decide which native call to execute.

Comment: @Bionix1441: when they build the JVM or some multi-target compiler (e.g. gcc), they specify with some build option that it has to target - say - x86 for Windows. That changes the code that gets compiled/the options built in the final executable. There's nothing magic about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers usually take a program written in high level language (e.g., C, Rust, Go) and produce an executable for a specific OS and architecture. If you have a compiler that can support multiple OSes and architectures, then it is likely that you would pass in the appropriate parameters via a command line flag or through some configuration file. The compiler could also try to infer the target OS (assuming the target OS is the same OS that is running the compiler) via environment variables such as "OS" and "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE".

Answer (score 2):

Target platform is determined by compiler using command-line flags, which are provided by the IDE, or developer. For example `-m32` flag for gcc, or `-mwindow` for MinGW. Complete set of this flags you could see in your compiler documentation.